# How to get value binded to [innerHTML] = "data" in textarea when edited by user in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

here ive binded my api response with json pipe in text area. now the user can change the binded value in text area and can save it again. but on save im not able to fetch the changed value in the ts file. help me asap.

html code:

```
                <textarea name="tfoText" 
                                 [innerHTML]="tso | json"
                                 #myItem
                                 placeholder="Text Editor">
                                </textarea>


ts code: 
on save click function:::  
  @ViewChild('myItem', { static: true })
  myItem!: ElementRef<any>;
console.log(this.myItem.nativeElement.innerHTML)
```

console prints the original binded value to innerHTML, not the edited value.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use innerHTML if you don't need it.

Second, use the correct Angular features to manage your bindings.

Finally, see how cleaner the code is.

```html
<textarea [(ngModel)]="tso"></textarea>
```